# Horizontally Scrolling Multiple Textviews

Tags: android, textview, android-scrollview, horizontalscrollview

In my application i have to implement an automatically scrolling multiple textviews.
Now I have a scrolling tetxview.But according to my requirement is that I have a string array(I have parsed and I have some string)..Consider the array may be

```
 string[] array = new string {"abc123", "123abc", "xyz123"};
```

Now i want this array to be displayed in that textview(which will scroll automatically).

I want it like this:

```
 abc123   123abc  xyz123------------------>this will scroll automatically but one by one or one after another
```

This is my textview(scrolling):

```
<TextView
android:text="Really Long Scrolling Text"
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:id="@+id/TextView03"
android:padding="5dip" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:textColor="#000000"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Programatically I did this:

```
    String[] array 
    = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.scrolling_banner_array);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String anArray : array) {
        sb.append(" ").append(anArray);
    }
    text.setText(sb.toString());
```

Now the array is continuously scrolling horizontally, but I want one text to be scrolled at a time and after finishing one text another text should come.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using gridview with item count one and scroll orientation vertical and enable scroll bars.

Hope it may work!